# Propogate keyPressEvent to top level QWidget in all cases

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard

I am working on an application where I want a certain keystroke (lets say the `Tab` key for this example) to always be handled by a particular `QWidget`. Lets say I have a hierarchy like this:

```
QWidget (top level window)
  ¬ QWidget X (the widget that should handle all Tab presses)
  ¬ QWidget (inner widget)
    ¬ ...
      ¬ ...
        ¬ QLineEdit (very deep into the hierarchy)
```

The `QLineEdit` currently has focus, and you can enter text into it. When the user presses `Tab`, I want it to be handled by `QWidget X` (near the very top of the hierarchy), to perform some action. How can I make sure a particular QWidget intercepts every single `Tab` key press if anything in the current window has focus?

Installing an event filter on every child `QWidget` is impractical, as the application is vast and liable to change.

Comment: Do you have to?  If a tab is pressed in QLineEdit, can you just iterate back up the parents until you find a QWidget X class, then call some OnTab() method of it?

Comment: QWidget X is not a parent of my QLineEdit, it will just go up to the top level widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having your `QWidget` override `keyPressEvent`, you can use `QShortcut`:

```
QShortcut *Shortcut = new QShortcut(this);
Shortcut->setKey(Qt::Key_Tab);
connect(Shortcut, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(TabPressed()));
```

And then in the `TabPressed()` slot, perform the action. This works regardless of any another `QWidget` having focus.